# CSRF validation IOS SDK DRUPAL

Tags: ios, drupal, drupal-7

I'm having problem with error 401 CSRF Validation failed 
By the way, i'm using Drupal IOS SDK.
I managed to do the login and register to my drupal website. However, after logging in I couldn't do task like Changing Password or Logging Out due to the error of 401 CSRF Validation failed. I have done alot of research about this  and know that I have to pass token along with any request to prevent this from happening. Still I couldnt manage this surpass this point.

Please Help.

Comment: Is it possible to get a link to an example, or some more information about what page is generating the CSRF error? It seems like this has been an issue lately: https://drupal.org/node/2012982

Comment: I'm now implementing this on my localhost sir, the problem appears after logging in and try to perform any tasks by the user. https://github.com/kylebrowning/drupal-ios-sdk​
there is a class called "DIOSCSRFAHTTPClient" which seems to be the one to handle the CSRF problem but as far as I can see. I didn't find any connection of this class being implemented/imported to be used in anywhere in my project. 

Thank you for answering too sir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed the problem now, by fixing up the code in AFHTTPCLIENT to make it to get the Token and send that CSRF token back to the server whenever the requests such as post, delete is fired.